# How do I draw a NSImage onto a NSView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, drawrect, nsimage

I'm pretty new to drawing images in general with Objective C. I have done image drawing in iPhone development, but now I want to do so on a Mac. In short, what is the Mac equivalent of the iPhone code below?

```
- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    UIImage *anotherimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alert.png"];
    CGPoint imagepoint = CGPointMake(10,0);
    [anotherimage drawAtPoint:imagepoint];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, assuming you don't want any image transparency and composition effects.

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    NSImage *anotherImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"alert.png"];
    [anotherImage drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(10,0) fromRect:rectToDrawImage operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
}
```

Comment: You probably know this, but you might want to move creation of the image out of **drawRect:** which has to be as clean and fast as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I needed to make a few changes, but it worked in the end. I added in NSMakeRect(0,0,[anotherImage size].width, [anotherImage size].height)

Comment: NSImage does not have a "frame" property, or so says Xcode.